# In MySQL, i am not being able to execute commands after a loop

Tags: mysql, cursor

I am using a cursor and a loop to execute a stored procedure on each item of a table. I need this to be done once a day. The procedure works and executes the daily procedure on each row of the table. This part works fine. But, when i try adding a logging to this at the end (updating of table RollupControl with time that this execution took) this command doesn't get executed at all...
I added two debugging selects, one inside the loop and the other outside. The one inside gets executed but the one outside doesn't...

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `RunX`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `RunX`()
RunX:BEGIN
    -- Roda Rup366 uma vez para cada Dispositivo
  DECLARE t0 DATETIME(2) DEFAULT NOW(2);
  DECLARE t0i FLOAT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE debug INT DEFAULT 1;

  DECLARE viddisp varchar(6);
  DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE _id BIGINT UNSIGNED;

  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR (SELECT ID FROM TableM m JOIN TableR r on m.ID = r.ID 
    WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(LastUpdatedTime,LastQueryedTime))/(60*60*24) > 1);
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;

  OPEN cur;
      RunXLoop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO _id;
        IF done THEN
          LEAVE RunX;
        END IF;
        SET viddisp = (SELECT IDDisp FROM TableM WHERE ID = _id);
        IF debug=1 THEN
          SELECT viddisp;
        END IF;
        CALL RunOnceADayProc(viddisp);
      END LOOP RunXLoop;
    IF debug=1 THEN
        SELECT t0i;
    END IF;  
    SET t0i = (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND,t0,NOW(2))/1000000);
    UPDATE RollupControl SET DH_Op = NOW(), ET = t0i WHERE ID = 366;
  CLOSE cur;  

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking

```
LEAVE RunX;
```

should be

```
LEAVE RunXLoop;
```